# Background apenas em uma parte do elemento

Tags: css, css3

Tenho um elemento, que ocupa 100% da página, porém ele tem um background até uma parte do elemento, até sei como fazer, só que preciso que se adapte a telas de 1024px e gostaria de saber outras formas de fazer, o bloco seria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso o background no título "Ofertas" que tem uma seta no final.

Comment: Não entendi a sua pergunta.

Comment: Nessa barra tem 2 backgrounds, duas cores e a seta, só que nessa imagem a barra tem 1920px, e teria de se adaptar para telas de 1024px, só que neste projeto, não posso utilizar recursos de media-queries.

Comment: Você pode setar o plano de fundo de duas divs, uma de cada lado e deixar elas se esticarem

Answer (score 1):

Meu caro!

Como o nosso colega [khaosdoctor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/17502/khaosdoctor) disse em [Background apenas em uma parte do elemento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41359/background-apenas-em-uma-parte-do-elemento#comment81759_41359):

> Você pode setar o plano de fundo de duas divs, uma de cada lado e deixar elas se esticarem

Utilize dois elementos `div` para obter o efeito desejado e utilize a propriedade `min-width:` para controlar a largura minima do seu elemento.

Ex.:

```css
html,body{
margin:0;
}

.linha{
width: 100%;
min-width: 768px;
}

.linha [class*="coluna-"]{
float:left;
position: relative;
height: 60px;
}

.linha [class*="coluna-"] > p {
padding: 0 30px;
}

.linha .coluna-a{
width: 40%;
background-color: #515151;
}

.linha .coluna-a::after{
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
right: -15px;
top: 15px;
content: ' ';
border-top: 15px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
border-left: 15px solid #515151;
}

.linha .coluna-b{
width: 60%;
background-color: #626262;
}
```

```html
<div class="linha">
    <div class="coluna-a">
        <p>Coluna A</p>
    </div>
    <div class="coluna-b">
        <p>Coluna B</p>
    </div>
</div>
```